# How can you change the color of a point in a UIView or a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimageview, uicolor

I'm trying to build my own "Flood Fill" implementation within a UIView. Everything is going well, but I can't figure out how to change the color of a specific point / pixel in a UIImageView or an a UIView.

How can I change the color of a point or pixel within a UIView?

**EDIT:**

Here my scenario:

1- on touch event:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:_image];
    UIColor *mycol=[self getPixelColorAtLocation:loc];
    if (mycondition) {

        _mylayer->point_=loc;
        _mylayer->color_=mycol;
        [_mylayer setNeedsDisplay];

    }
}
```

draw rect on my custom `UIView`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (point_.x>0) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color_.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(point_.x,point_.y, 1.0, 1.0));
    }
}
```

my point now is "every time i called `[_mylayer setNeedsDisplay];` the placed points (new color) are removed and a new point (just 1 point) appeared.

any idea

Comment: you could place a custom view on top of the image view

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Methods to change the color of a point/pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Before your `drawRect` method is called the entire context is cleared. You have to be able to recreate all your content at any time, not just one point. If you're subclassing another class of your own, don't forget to call the super implementation so it can add its drawing contribution.

Comment: 1- what dow you mean by "ou have to be able to recreate all your content"

Comment: when the method gets called, you have to have ready all the data to create the content your view holds. for example, in the code you posted, you only draw one single rectangle, but you should draw them all (the new one and the old ones). If your update region limits to a rectangle area, you should update only that specific region, but still you should have data (position, color etc) for all your view kept for later use.

Comment: so help full ideas, but can you give me idea how to update a specific region?